# jQuery UI Pulsate in Chrome

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, google-chrome

I'm having trouble getting some text to pulsate using the jquery UI plugin in Chrome.

Here is my html,

```
<div id="discount-banner">
  <div><p>Special <?php echo $val?>10.00 DISCOUNT Activated - Now Only <?php echo $val ?>27.95 + FREE BONUSES</p></div>
</div>
```

Any my javascript,

```
$('#discount-banner > div').pulsate();
```

Comment: do you have a link for the plugin? or is it one you wrote yourself?

Comment: jQuery 1.4.4 & jQueryUI 1.8.7

Comment: Pulsate plugin, http://jqueryui.com/demos/effect/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sod's law. Managed to solve my own question right after I posted it.

```
$('#div').effect('pulsate')
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this new [plugin](http://kilianvalkhof.com/jquerypulsate/)

Works like charm and the pulsate effect works on all browsers .

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.